# Is the Swiss Travel Pass also a Swiss Half Fare Card?

Tags: switzerland

Does the Swiss Travel Pass (Rail Pass) also work like a Swiss Half Fare Card ?

Do I get discounts for [Mount Titlis](https://www.titlis.ch/en/info/general/Prices) ?

Comment: But the real bargain IMHO is that it doubles as a Museum pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swiss Travel Pass and the Half-Fare (*Halbtax*) are separate products. However, yes, according to the discounts tab on [the pricing page on titlis.ch](https://www.titlis.ch/en/info/general/Prices) and the map linked on the bottom of [the SBB page on the Swiss Travel Pass](https://www.sbb.ch/en/leisure-holidays/inspiration/international-guests/swiss-travel-pass.html), Swiss Travel Pass holders are entitled to a 50% discount on the Titlis area transport.